# how to call a method from select tag in angular 6 on page load

Tags: angular, angular6

I have few drop downs, and I need to fill values on dropdowns dynamically by using the same function call. I have an array of objects from where I will fill up the values in drop down.

so Idea is I will pass the name of drop down as an argument and iterate the array of values and will return the list of values to display into drop down

Question is: How to call any function in Angular 6 from a select box when the page loads? I don't want to call the function on click, or change, I want to call only when page loads on all select tag.

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]='name' placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fieldValue of fieldValues" [value]="fieldValue.name">
        {{fieldValue.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

I want to call a method in select tag on page load like.

```
<mat-select ng-Init="getData(name)" [(ngModel)]='name' placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let fieldValue of fieldValues" [value]="fieldValue.name">
        {{fieldValue.name}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

But as we know there is no concept of ng-Init in angular 6, so what can i do.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks
Can a standard life-cycle hook be used? ngOnInit specifically.

Comment: Can you please explain what you meant by this How to call any function in Angular 6 from a select box when the page loads? I don't want to call the function on click, or change, I want to call only when page loads on all select tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnInit life cycle hook. Example code is below:

```
import {  OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
     //Code to initialize arrays goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: But i need to call a function from all select tag with different argument on page load.

Comment: You can use variables to store the initial values that you need to pass to the function, and then call functions based on that.

Comment: I have more than 100 drop down so i don't want create 100 variables.

Comment: If you are using reactive forms you could loop over the formcontrols and pass formcontrol name to the getData function.

Comment: that is why i want to call a method and pass different argument in it, that method fetch data on argument base.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept link ng-init in angular new versions. All you can do is create a directive

```
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';    
@Directive({
    selector: '[ngInit]'
})
export class NgInit {
    @Input() ngInit;
    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.ngInit) {
            this.ngInit();
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this -

```
<div *ngIf="ramadan.date === date && ramadan.time === clock">
  <div *ngIf="ramadan.checked" [ngInit]="play"></div>
  <div *ngIf="!ramadan.checked" [ngInit]="pause"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As You have said you need to build drop-down while your page load & you dont want to upload on (**click**) or (**onchange**) event.

You can try below code as per your requirement. **Let me know if anything is unclear to you**

```
    <mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods[0]" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>



<mat-form-field >
  <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" >
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods[1]" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**this is my ts code**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  foods = [];

  ngOnInit(){
    this.abc();
  }
  abc() {
    this.foods[0] = [
      {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
      {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
      {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
    ];

    this.foods[1] = [
      {value: 'abc', viewValue: 'abc'},
      {value: 'zyz', viewValue: 'zyz'},
      {value: 'jhg', viewValue: 'kjh'}
    ];
  }
```